# Javascript - Simply identify on which network the browser is connected

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, network-programming

I set up a node js web server, which is serving images links in a JSON file. One link is referring to an image on the internet, and the other link is referring to a local directory in my home server.

The web server is online, not on my home server. *For bandwidth usage purposes*, the web server is only serving image links. If the client is connected trough my home connection, it uses the local link, and if it is not, it uses the internet link.

Currently, I serve a JSON file containing the links, and always select the internet one, on the client side, because I do not know how to make the client understand that he is on my local network.

Is there something existing? I have done research about getting the mac address of the router (first hop), the network ssid, ... but it doesn't seem to be achievable only with JavaScript.

so, basically, here is my setup :

**Home network :**

- Home server (images stored locally)
- Potential client connected through this connection

**Web-hosted content :**

- Web server (node js)
- FTP (images stored)
- Potential client connected

In any situation, the client needs an internet connection, since the node server is online. However, if the client is on the same (my local network) network as the local home server, he should use the local links for getting image.

I need one of these two solutions :

- The client knows if he is on my local network, and then picks up the 
  good link
- The web server knows where the client comes from, and serves directly
  the good link (so, no problem on client side). The problem with that one is that my web server is not hosted on my home network.

Comment: Does the local client's IP start with `192.`?

Comment: @JuniusRendel: node.js is a JS-based server language.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not stupid, but : " I do not know how to make the client understand that he is on my local network."

Comment: The OP could easily set a boolean to make the client select local urls.

Comment: Yes, in fact, i shouldn't have mentionned node-js since I am looking for client-side solutions... The client IP could start with anything, since this is a web hosted server, it is reachable from anywhere.

Comment: if you use a vpn to connect to your webserver it is very easy to do this server-side

Comment: So, you are trying to make the client decide if it's on the same network as the server, _without_ the server interfering in it, in any way? That's not possible.

Comment: Let me edit my question, maybe i am not clear enough ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to write something server side, to get this to work.

***Only*** the server can tell wether or not the client is on the same network as the server is. Client-side JS simply doesn't have access to network information.

You'd do something like this:

On a client request, the server:

- Checks if the client's connecting IP is a local one.
- If so, set some kind of boolean that the client side can read.
- The client then selects either the local or the remote url set, depending on that boolean.

Choosing what urls to include in your pages is a little simpler:

On a client request, the server:

- Checks if the client's connecting IP is a local one.
- If so, includes local urls in the requested webpages. Otherwise, include remote urls.

Comment: Server side seems definitely more interesting to me. Since the web server is not on my local network, is it possible to compare the client's IP with my home server IP ? (so, knowing that the web server is 'local' for nobody)

Comment: Wait, what? So, you have a web server that hosts the site, and a home server where things like images are stored? Then you'd be best comparing connecting IP's to yours, indeed. Connect to your server from a few different devices on your network to see the similarities in their IPs.

Comment: Exactly ! And a FTP server too, for non-local clients.

Comment: Then the "processes" described in my answer should do the trick.

Comment: I will go for the server-side comparison between the client's IP and the local image storage server's !

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the following `server connection lost` PHP, jQuery and Bootstrap CSS. It checks every second to see if the browser is able to connect to a single pixel image `<?=__DOMAIN_URL__;?>/network_access.gif` hosted on the server, where `<?=__DOMAIN_URL__;?>` is PHP syntax for piping in the server URL to the HTML. The javascript `this.img.onerror` function is called if the image connection cannot be established.

```
<?php 
// ============================== start plugin for displaying server downtime ?>
<div id="myModalDT" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog mt-4 pt-2" style="min-width: 75% !important;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body p-3">
                Server disconnect/network outage
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    // server connection check
    var timer = $.timer(function() {
        this.img = new Image();
        d = new Date();
        // if the image will not load then we need to alert the user that the network connection was lost ?>
        this.img.onerror = function() {
            $('#myModalDT').find(".modal-body").html('<span class="h2"><strong>Server connection lost.</strong><br/>Checking connection at '+d.toString('dddd, MMMM ,yyyy') + '<hr/>This message is likely due to the server being restarted and this message should automatically disappear once the connection is restored. <br/><br/> If this message does not disappear in several minutes then refresh the page.</span>');
            $('#myModalDT').modal('show');
        };

        // if the image is loaded then hide the alert
        this.img.onload = function () {
            $('#myModalDT').modal('hide');
        }
        <?php // looks on the server to see if we can get to an image file ?>
        this.img.src = "<?=__DOMAIN_URL__;?>/network_access.gif?cacheDiscard=" + d.getTime();
    });
    <?php // setting a timer to check that we have network connectivity every second ?>
    timer.set({ time : 1000, autostart : true });
</script>
<?php 
// ============================== end plugin for displaying server downtime ?>
```

Stripping down the code above to javascript, you could essentially simply replace `<?=__DOMAIN_URL__;?>` with your local server URL and if the `this.img.onload` function is called then you can have your javascript replace image reference URLs with the local URL, and if the `this.img.onerror` function is called (meaning you cannot connect to the local server) then you replace the image URL with the 'cloud' server URL.

```
<script>
this.img = new Image(); // create an empty image object 

d = new Date(); // we do not want the browser to cache the image we are checking so we get the current timestamp to clear the cache

this.img.src = "http://localhost-whatever/network_access.gif?cacheDiscard=" + d.getTime();  // this sets the contents of our image object to one of our locally hosted images, with the cache busting timestamp included

this.img.onerror = function() {
  // were were not able to connect locally if this were called and should use the server hosted images    
};

this.img.onload = function () {
  // if we made it here then we can use locally sourced images
}
</script>
```